# Detecting long button presses in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a program that repeatedly executes a function and when a button is pressed it executes another function. When that same button is pressed for at least 3 seconds it ends the program.

I started using the waitKey() function in OpenCV since my program already uses that library, however, I plan on using a physical button connected to a Raspberry Pi in the future.

This is what I have so far, as you can see I am stuck on the long pressing part.

```
def buttonPressDetector():
    while (True):
        key = cv2.waitKey(0)
        if key == 69 or key == 101: #'E' or 'e' on the keyboard
            if (MODE + 1) > 2:
                MODE = 0
            else:
                MODE += 1
        #if long press for 3 or more seconds:
            #stopCondition = True
MODE = 0
stopCondition = False
btd = threading.Thread(target=self.buttonPressDetector, daemon=True)
btd.start()

while (not stopCondition):    
    if MODE == 0:
        myFunction(MODE)
    elif MODE == 1:
        myFunction2(MODE)
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Well... what do you suppose are the logical steps to solve the problem? In complete, English sentences, what steps should be taken? (Some things to think about: would it be useful to know the system time when the button is pressed? Would it be useful to know the system time when the button is released? Given the `MODE` value, what rules can we use to tell whether the button was already down when we check the `cv2.waitKey` result? If the button was already down, how should we change the logic that handles the `key` result?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I definitely need to time when the key is pressed and released, but I don't think there are functions that track this in cv2. Should I look for another library or are you suggesting that there is a doable logic with the MODE variable?

Comment: Well, [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to find a way to get the time, perhaps using the standard library? For example, how about [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+get+the+current+time) to look that up?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was reffering to OnPress() OnRelease() listener type of functions, not the system time ones, sorry

Comment: If you want to take an event-driven approach, then maybe it doesn't make much sense to *also* use a loop. I don't think `opencv` is that kind of library, though (I'm not very familiar).

Comment: calling waitKey from a thread is a terrible idea. some GUI toolkits (that OpenCV can use) consider that an **error**. use a proper GUI toolkit for this. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for making GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

More than once you're going to
wait for a key.
Note the [`time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) when you do,
assigning it to `pressed_since`.

Occasionally you will notice that no key
is being pressed. When that happens,
assign a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) of `math.inf`,
to indicate lack of keypress.

Now it's easy.
If you notice key is currently pressed,
and `time() - pressed_since > 3`,
you should end the program,
as it has been pressed for more than three seconds.

---

> ```
> if key == 69 or key == 101: #'E' or 'e' on the keyboard
> ```

That's not a great line.
How can we tell?
Because a comment was needed.
Now, it's a very nice comment,
I'm glad it's there.
But it would be better to write the code
so that none was needed.
Strive for self-explanatory code.

Prefer

```
if chr(key) in ('e', 'E'):
```

or `in 'eE'`, or better

```
if chr(key).upper() == 'E':
```

Comment: thank you for the response and the feedback!